# Where should I ask my question?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I asked the following question on Stack Overflow, but it was closed:
http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/14602582/is-there-a-metric-for-visits

Where would this question be appropriate and could I get it answered? It is not a programming question on the Facebook API, but rather it is about which metrics to use. I thought it was a valid question.

Answer (score 2):

Since it seems you're asking about the API [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com) would be, I'd think, the proper venue. You should clean up your question and make it clear(er) that you're asking about the API.

Facebook questions, in general, belong on [Web Apps](http://webapps.stackexchange.com), unless they're about programming.